# PHP: Google Analytics API pagePath filters are not working, taking all traffic instead of just path

Tags: php, api, analytics

So I am crawling my blog to detect which articles have issues (broken links and linking to products we no longer sell). So I am trying to get the traffic since the article was created to a year later (unless its been done within a year, in which case it is new), then add the traffic data for that. I am doing this to prioritise the list as there are over 1000 articles with issues.

So the function of getting the anlytics was taken from Google Analytics API documentation and modified:

```
function getResults($analytics, $profileId, $page, $startdays, $enddays) {
return $analytics->data_ga->get(
   'ga:' . $profileId,
   $startdays.'daysAgo',
   $enddays.'daysAgo',
   'ga:sessions',
    array(
    'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=='.$page.',ga:medium==organic'));
}

function printResults($results) {
  // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
  // the profile name and total sessions.
  if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

    // Get the profile name.
    $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

    // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
    $rows = $results->getRows();
    $sessions = $rows[0][0];

    // Print the results.
    print "Total sessions: $sessions\n";
  } else {
    print "No results found.\n";
  }
}
```

The code to actually put these parameters into the function is:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `articles_tbl` LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $url=$row["article_url"];
        $published_date=$row["date_published"]; 
        $your_date = strtotime($published_date);
        $now = time();
        $datediff=$now-$your_date;
        $startdays = round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
        $enddays=$startdays-365;
        if($enddays<0){
            $enddays=1;
        }

        $analytics = initializeAnalytics();
        $profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);

        //The domain has been removed for obvious reasons
        //this is to get the folders in the URL:
        //"/blog/news/pagefolder/"

        $page=str_replace(DOMAIN,"",$url);
        $results = getResults($analytics, $profile, $page, $startdays, $enddays);
        printResults($results);

        echo "for url: ".$page." between ".$startdays." days ago and ".$enddays." days ago.";
    }
}
```

So this currently outputs: "Total sessions: 999999 for url: /blog/news/pagefolder/ between 859 days ago and 494 days ago.

Now this figure above is the whole website traffic for that period (confirmed in Analytics manually), but I want the exact number of sessions for that URL only. Nothing I do will show this or change the traffic in anyway. I can only assume it gives me the sessions before the filters are applied, thus it is always the same? I have been staring at this for hours and no luck, everything I have read says that by just doing pagePath== instead of pagePath=@ should make it exact, but no suck luck, still get all website traffic...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the organic filter. It was breaking the filters so none worked.